# List of Admin-installed 3rd party apps in Google domain - google admin sdk

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm using Google Directory APIs to list all 3rd party apps granted by the user with the help of  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/tokens/list API. 
Is it possible to find out which 3rd party app in a domain was installed by an admin using this or any other API?

Thanks!

Comment: For this you may try getting the admin activity report mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin) and use filters mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list).  Let me know if that works for your project.

Comment: @KRR, I am aware of the reports API. I am looking for a more direct API which provides the list of apps with more details. For example, when a domain admin adds a new market place app for a particular organization in the domain, the reports API's audit log doesn't seem to give this information clearly.